# Gracefully Handling Empty Facebook Quick Replies

Tags: c#, facebook, botframework

I was testing some flows in our bot yesterday particularly where we are using quick replies for things like the users phone number and email address.

I had installed the messenger application on my iPad (not the full Facebook application) and I had logged in using the credentials for my main Facebook account.

Now I have read that a "messenger only account" isn't the same thing as a full Facebook account (I can't find the documentation for this just now).

However I did expect the email and phone quick replies to still be populated as per the details Facebook holds in my main Facebook account profile.

We can obviously word things with the expectation that these quick replies will be empty but it would be nice to be able to customise a bit further when we know there won't be a button for the user to tap.

Is there any way to detect the likelyhood of these quick replies being populated ahead of time?

Our code that creates our quick replies are simple helper methods, such as:

```
public static JObject GetFacebookEmailChoice()
{
    var channelData = new JObject();
    var child = new JObject {{"content_type", "user_email"}};
    channelData.Add("quick_replies", new JArray(child));
    return channelData;
}
```

These are used like:

```
var reply = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
reply.Text = questionText;
reply.ChannelData = ChoiceGenerator.GetFacebookEmailChoice();
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added the code examples.

Comment: Quick replies from the BotFramework appear to be working fine on the iOS Messenger app. Not sure why it wouldn't work on an iPad. I'd recommend updating the iPad and the Messenger app. Additionally, as far as I know, there is no way to proactively know what device the user is on.

Comment: No the issue is not that they do or don't work, they are working fine. The issue is that there is no guarantee that a quick reply will be populated by messenger or Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to know whether the **phone or email** quick reply will work since we can't previously know if the user's profile does have a phone number or email.

What i would do is send 2 quick replies

1. First one will be a **Phone** or **Email** quick reply
2. Second one will be an text with payload quick reply ( Input Email/Phone ) from which the user can click and then go into a dialog where you receive his email or phone

If the user has his information in his profile then both will render, the user can either click the Email or Phone quick reply directly or click the second one and manually input the info

If the user does not have these information in his profile then the second quick reply will only render and the user will still have the ability to give the needed info